# Как запретить переход по ссылке при клике на определеный элемент внутри неё?

Tags: javascript

В интернет магазине есть каталог товаров, каждый товар полностью оформлен в виде ссылки.

Но внутри этого блока есть ещё и кнопки, как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку внутри ссылки не происходило перехода?

Comment: [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спасибо говорить @Grundy

 В песочнице, что кликается, а что нет можно понять по консоли. Магия в `event.stopPropagination`

```js
document.getElementById('123').onclick = worker;

function worker(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // do your code here
  console.log('button clicked');
}
document.querySelector('a').onclick = worker2;

function worker2() {
  console.log('a clicked');
}
```

```css
a div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a target="_blank" href='google.ru'>
  <div>123</div>
  <button id='123'>Моя кнопка</button>
</a>
```

Comment: Не подскажете почему не работает в jq? https://jsfiddle.net/bk9bwotg/

Comment: Не спец в jquery. Аналогичный вашему вопрос по ссылке - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535600/stop-propagation-doesnt-work 
Судя по всему это проблема jquery

Comment: Нашел более элегантное решение https://jsfiddle.net/r71p5o63/

Answer (score 1):

onclick="[event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)"

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]