# Как переопределить клик внутри ссылки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть ссылка, и внутри ссылки текст. Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на спан ссылка не открывалась, а выполнялась JS-функция?

```
<a href="http://site.com/">Текст <span>текст</span> текст</a>
```

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/696417/256824

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В **jQuery**:

```js
$('.nolink').on('click', function(){
  /*
    Тут уже можете писать что хотите..
  */
  console.info('Чё? Не открывается?');
  
  return false; // это отменит переход по ссылке.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="nolink" href="https://blablabla.bla/">Нажми</a>
```

---

Отменить при нажатии на `span`.

Учитывайте, что у ссылки `<a>` должен быть свой таргет, чтобы можно было нажать и на `<span>` и на `<a>`

```js
$('.nolink > span').on('click', function(){
  /*
    Тут уже можете писать что хотите..
  */
  console.info('Чё? Не открывается?');
  
  return false; // это отменит переход по ссылке.
});
```

```css
.nolink {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
}

.nolink span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

.nolink:hover,
.nolink span:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="nolink" href="https://blablabla.bla/"><span>Нажми</span></a>
```

Comment: Нужно именно, чтобы ссылка работала, при клике на span нет.

Comment: @ПушкинОлег, дополнил ответ

Comment: @РустамГимранов, о как. Хоть отписались, уже хорошо. Думал просто лепят)

Comment: @РустамГимранов, скорее всего ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯